# Eclipse - Can't get file in "res" directory

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I know this sort of question has been asked numerous times, but I'm having trouble retrieving a file from teh res folder in an eclipse rcp plugin. One thing I've noted is that if I print the absolute path for a root file (new File(".")), it says I'm in the eclipse folder location and not my workspace for some reason. The default workspace location seems to be set to this, so I'm thinking this could be part of the issue because when I do new File("res/somefile.txt") its lookin in the eclipse location and not the plugin right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513729/create-file-in-resources-source-folder-in-java-programmatically - check this question's answer.

Comment: Use `FileLocator` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34924046/2670892)

Comment: Thanks guys. The FileLocator worked! I found this post to help me [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431616/relative-filepath-to-access-resourceshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431616/relative-filepath-to-access-resources]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get resources path from a eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923454/how-to-get-resources-path-from-a-eclipse-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Greg's comment above I used the below code to get the file after injkecting in the bundle.

```
    IPath path = new Path("res/icons/preferences.gif");

    URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);

    URL iconUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);

    Image image = new Image(parent.getDisplay(), iconUrl.getPath());
```